# Visual Studio Code Compiler not compile correctly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I want to use IDE Visual studio Code for **C++**. I install the extension and follow the steps of the YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0xTgyCwsAo

But when I press Ctrl+Shift+B for running task build, it gives the error:

> **Failed to launch external program sh -c.
>   spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT**

How to fix it?

Comment: Superficially, it may mean you don't have `cmd.exe` installed in `C:\WINDOWS\system32` — is the file (and the directory) there?  If so, take a look at the permissions, etc.  If it is not there, then find out how to install it.  (No: I've no idea — I don't have a Windows system to experiment with.)

Comment: Are you trying to run VS Code on a Windows or a Linux system?